# QListView flushes slowly when there are three QListViews in a QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistview, qstringlistmodel

I customized my data model `AnnotationListModel` inherited from QStringListModel.

The purpose of `AnnotationListModel` class, is to add checkboxes for data items and achieve exclusion between data items.

Now, I create three QListView and `AnnotationListModel` objects in a QDialog. The data item in the model is added as a checkbox, and is exclusive.

I can check the checkbox in QListView, but the checked status can't display quickly.

How can I enable QListView to flush quickly?

```
class AnnotationListModel :public QStringListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AnnotationListModel(AnnotationType annType, const QStringList& stringList, QObject* parent = nullptr);
    ~AnnotationListModel() {};

protected:
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

signals:
    void sendAnnotation(const AnnotationType& annoType, const QString& annotation);

private:
    AnnotationType m_annoType;
    QStringList m_stringList;
    QMap<QString, bool> m_stringList_map; //<annotationName,checked>
};

AnnotationListModel::AnnotationListModel(AnnotationType annType, const QStringList& stringList, QObject* parent)
    :QStringListModel(parent), m_stringList(stringList), m_annoType(annType)
{
    setStringList(m_stringList);
    for (auto& value : m_stringList)
    {
        m_stringList_map[value] = false;
    }
}

Qt::ItemFlags AnnotationListModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }
    return Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | QStringListModel::flags(index);
}

QVariant AnnotationListModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if (m_stringList_map[m_stringList.at(index.row())] == true)
        {
            return Qt::Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            return Qt::Unchecked;
        }
    }
    else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return m_stringList.at(index.row());
    }

    return QStringListModel::data(index, role);
}

bool AnnotationListModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if (value == Qt::Checked)
        {
            for (int i{ 0 }; i < m_stringList.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (i != index.row())
                {
                    m_stringList_map[m_stringList.at(i)] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_stringList_map[m_stringList.at(i)] = true;
                    sendAnnotation(m_annoType, m_stringList.at(i));
                }
            }
        }
        else if (value == Qt::Unchecked)
        {
            m_stringList_map[m_stringList.at(index.row())] = false;
        }
    }

    return QStringListModel::setData(index, value, role);
}
```

Create three `AnnotationListModel` objects:

```
switch (itr_kind.key())
{
case AnnotationType::CounCode:
    m_counCodeModel = new AnnotationListModel(AnnotationType::CounCode, l_annoStrList);
    m_uiDialog->listView_country->setModel(m_counCodeModel);
    connect(m_counCodeModel, &AnnotationListModel::sendAnnotation, this, &AnnotationDialog::sendAnnotation);
    break;

case AnnotationType::DriSide:
    m_driSideModel = new AnnotationListModel(AnnotationType::DriSide, l_annoStrList);
    m_uiDialog->listView_driving->setModel(m_driSideModel);
    connect(m_driSideModel, &AnnotationListModel::sendAnnotation, this, &AnnotationDialog::sendAnnotation);
    break;

case AnnotationType::RoadType:
    m_roadTypeModel = new AnnotationListModel(AnnotationType::RoadType, l_annoStrList);
    m_uiDialog->listView_road->setModel(m_roadTypeModel);
    connect(m_roadTypeModel, &AnnotationListModel::sendAnnotation, this, &AnnotationDialog::sendAnnotation);
}
```

The Dialog is opened through `mainwindow`.

[image]

Comment: Your question is missing the purpose of the class you are creating, which I think is an important detail. Please add what `AnnotationListModel` is for in details.

Comment: I have add the complete definition of Annotation class.

Comment: Just read your latest edit: so you want to add checkboxes to you items and ensure not more than 1 of them is checked, yes?

Comment: sorry， I just add purpose description. The purpose of AnnotationListModel class is to add checkboxes for data items and achieve exclusion between data items.

Comment: yes, add checkboxes and only select one data item once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you have made 4 mistakes but the important ones are the first 2:

- The correct approach to add a functionality to an existing model (`QStringListModel` in your case) is with a proxy model (a subclass of `QAbstractProxyModel`). It works just as well but is easier to implement and way more flexible since it can be used with any model type.
- As you want your checkboxes to be exclusive, you only need to remember the one that is checked, there was no need to have a whole `QMap<...>` container for that.
  I believe this is where most of the computation time was being wasted in your code, especially when testing the dialog in debug mode (containers have many, many checks that are done only in debug, making them way slower to use than in release).
  At least, it was right not to save the checked index as a `QModelIndex`.
- You forgot to emit `dataChanged` signals from your `setData` method.
- You forgot to return `false`/`true` from your `setData` method. To be precise, a boolean is indeed returned but only by `QStringListModel::setData(...)`, which is not what you want to do.

The below `AnnotationProxyModel` implements exclusive checkboxes for any model you want to implement. It derives `QIdentityProxyModel` and remember the checked index thanks to a `QPersistentModelIndex` (which unlike `QModelIndex` is OK to save).
I let you check if you really need to keep the `Q_OBJECT` macro and your signal(s) in the below definition and if yes, add them back yourself.

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QIdentityProxyModel>
class AnnotationProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel {
public:
    AnnotationProxyModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role) override;
private:
    QPersistentModelIndex checkedIndex;
};

AnnotationProxyModel::AnnotationProxyModel(QObject* parent) : 
    QIdentityProxyModel(parent),
    checkedIndex()
{
}

QVariant AnnotationProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::CheckStateRole: return QVariant((checkedIndex == index) ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
    default: return QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);
    }
}

Qt::ItemFlags AnnotationProxyModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return QIdentityProxyModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
}

bool AnnotationProxyModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::CheckStateRole: {
        if (checkedIndex == index) {
            if (value.value<Qt::CheckState>() != Qt::Unchecked) // Trying to check the already checked index -> return false
                return false;
            else {
                checkedIndex = QPersistentModelIndex(); // Unchecking the already checked index -> return true;
                emit dataChanged(index, index, { Qt::CheckStateRole });
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (value.value<Qt::CheckState>() == Qt::Unchecked) // Trying to uncheck an index that is already unchecked -> return false
                return false;
            else {
                QModelIndex uncheckedIndex = checkedIndex;
                checkedIndex = QPersistentModelIndex(index);
                emit dataChanged(uncheckedIndex, uncheckedIndex, { Qt::CheckStateRole });
                emit dataChanged(index, index, { Qt::CheckStateRole });
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    default: return QIdentityProxyModel::setData(index, value, role);
    }
}
```

Like  any other proxy model, it is used by calling `setSourceModel(...)` with your `QStringListModel`, i.e. in that fashion:

```cpp
AnnotationProxyModel* checkModel = new AnnotationProxyModel(view);
checkModel->setSourceModel(countryModel);
view->setModel(checkModel);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance and fixed my problem. And let me know how use Qt model correctly. I need to learn the QIdentityProxyModel, I never used it.

Comment: Yea the fact I did not intend to keep your `AnnotationListModel` in my answer is why I was being so annoying with getting the purpose right. You should spare time to have a look in the documentation at the classes that inherit `QAbstractProxyModel`. Many people with less experience misunderstand `QIdentityProxyModel` as a class that does nothing (which is basically true), hence has no reason to exist (which is wrong; let alone compared to other proxy models, `QIdentityProxyModel` is one of the most useful model classes).

Comment: @Atmo Considering the size of the model, I sincerely doubt that the issue is the iteration through the map, and is almost certainly caused just by the missing `dataChanged` (and proper return from `setData()`): the result of that is that the view is only updated upon further user interaction (any event that causes the view to update its contents, like mouse movements or focus changes), and that is commonly mistaken as a "delay".

Comment: @musicamante just in case: what I called the "important mistakes" are the ones that are harder to correct, not the ones with a bigger impact on "performance". It is easy to add the missing signals, much less so to change the class or a whole logic that relied on a `QMap`. So what you say is possible (probable?) but to my defense, I don't think OP was showing all the data he has on his screenshot. I can certainly imagine a big enough model would lag with the approach he had taken. I have not checked if a full country model, in debug mode, would but I did not want to rule out the possibility.

Comment: I don't think this was the important part of my answer anyway... If that stresses you out, I can edit the sentence "*I believe this is where most of the computation time was being wasted*" out for you.

Comment: @Atmo It doesn't stress me out :-) I was just pointing out that it probably wasn't the cause of the issue, as it's quite common to mistake a "delay" in the update of the view when caused by a missing `dataChanged` (they "see" a delay, believing it's caused by computation, but it's actually an update possibly caused by inadvertently moving the mouse). That said, from the context of the question we can safely assume that the country model would have less than 200 entries: would the debug mode cause such visible and significant delays for such a map? (that's a honest question, I don't use C++)

Comment: Yea, there are several reasons why debug is so much slower than release: sanity checks made when on debug, skipped on release (issues are supposed to be detected during debug runs), optimizations added by the compiler in release, usually disabled in debug, etc. To give a comparison, I am currently working on an algorithm (STL containers): for a given input, it completes in release in 25-30ms, and in 2400-2600ms in debug. Not a small difference... For Qt, I have experienced a model lagging **horribly** in debug (on scroll down); the same thing with 10x the data was completely fine in release.

Comment: As for whether 200 entries would be enough to cause visible lag, most likely not in release. I lack the benchmarks to tell about debug mode but what my above case (100x factor between both) tells is that an operation taking less than 1 frame on release may very well take 1 full second (in other words, forever) on debug. As far as I am concerned, a perceptible lag (5 frames or more @ 60FPS) was a possibility.